# Tamaño de un FileInputStream

Tags: java

practicando con el tema de los streams hice un programa que copiaba archivos.En un momento dado me encontre con el problema de que la cantidad de bytes del archivo copiado erea menor al del archivo original.Que fue lo que paso?Recorde que hay que indicar en un array la cantidad estimada de bytes que tiene ese archivo.El metodo "available" da un valor estimado de la cantidad de bytes que tiene ese archivo.Mi duda es si puede en algun caso llegar a ser menor la cantidad estimada de lo que en realidad pesa el archivo por lo que haria que el archivo no se pueda abrir.

Otra duda es por que cuando uso un ArrayList  sin indicarle tamaño para almacenar los bytes del archivo me guarda la mitad o menos de los bytes que en realidad son.

Comment: Si tienes otra duda hazla en otra pregunta

Answer (score 3):

creo que hay una pequeña confusión. Un stream no te puede decir el tamaño "completo" del stream... precisamente porque es un Stream... se va a leer secuencialmente y el propio Stream no sabe cual es el tamaño final. La cantidad de bytes `available` va a ir cambiando en el tiempo, a medida que leas del stream y a medida que el propio stream vaya leyendo de su fuente de datos.. puede crecer, puede disminuir. Finalmente, el tamaño del archivo lo podrías obtener a traves de `File`.

Aclaración: no es que conozca la API... estoy haciendo un *educated guess*, por si acaso.

Answer (score 0):

```
 lector=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path));
    int contador=0;
    array=new int[lector.available()];
```

Entonces como actua esto?Porque al ser un stream tengo entendido que es un flujo que no almacena datos,sino que es transitivo.Como puede ser que si no se sabe al tamaño el array incremente,si esto no se puede?

Comment: Esto no debe ir en una respuesta amigo.